# Probability that a random variable has a greater absolute value than the sample mean of iid random variable

Tags: random-variable, integral, absolute-value

I have encountered a problem which involves finding the probability that an observation of a random variable has a greater absolute value than the sample mean of an independent set of observations of the same random variable.

Anyone have any idea how to proceed? Ideally, I am looking for some general properties of this probability as a function of the underlying distribution. The underlying distribution can be assumed to be lognormal, shifted by some constant.

My thoughts so far are to take a normal approximation for the sample mean by the central limit theorem. I'm not sure if that helps all that much. Anyone have an idea of how to proceed?

Comment: Is this "underlying distribution" common to all the observations, both of the "random variable" and of the data from which the means are computed?  If so, all data are positive: why do you refer to the "absolute value"?  Something looks amiss here.

Comment: Ah right I'm sorry. Yes the underlying distribution is common to all observations. And the lognormal distribution can be shifted by some amount, so can take negative values.

Comment: You will need to use numerical methods (including simulation) unless the means are based on *huge* datasets and/or the geometric standard deviation of the distribution is small, in which case the Normal approximation (or a Lognormal approximation of the distributions of the means, called "conservation of lognormality" in certain circles) might be okay. Without making your question more specific, addressing "general properties" looks a little too open ended: please indicate *which* properties and *which* distributions you have in mind.